# Background border radius with linear gradient

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to make 2 background, as follow the image. I'm trying to do with linear-gradient and border radius, but I'm getting only a 90º border and don't know how to change the border.

[image: Linear gradient width radius]

here is the code

```
background-image: linear-gradient(left, #e3e3e3, #e3e3e3 30%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%), radial-gradient(circle at top left, #f00,#e3e3e3);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e3e3e3, #e3e3e3 30%, transparent 30%, transparent 100%);
border-top-right-radius: 36px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 36px;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
.box {
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) left/100px 100% no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at left,blue 44%,transparent 45%) 100px 0/74px 74px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 Some content here 
</div>
```

You can also introduce CSS variable for more control:

```css
.box {
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) left/var(--p,50px) 100% no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at left,blue 44%,transparent 45%) var(--p,50px) 0/74px 74px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 Some content here 
</div>
<div class="box" style="--p:20px">
 Some content here 
</div>
<div class="box" style="--p:150px">
 Some content here 
</div>
```